# Output messages when running eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed the latest version of Eclipse.  I have it configured the way I like, when when I start it I get 2 messages about log4j not being initialized properly.  I added -Dlog4.debug=true to the eclipse.ini file and this does nto give me any additional insight.  There is the output I get:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder@6159286e
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EqunioxClassLoader@5834198f[org.apache.log4j:1.2.15.v201012070815(id=55)] class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder@6159286e
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EqunioxClassLoader@5834198f[org.apache.log4j:1.2.15.v201012070815(id=55)] class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Could not find resource: [null].
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.spotify.docker.client.DockerConfigReader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I have tried a few things, including adding a log4j.properties file in the location where org.apache.log4j is located (/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins).  I also tried putting one in my home directory.  I also trued addine a log4j.rootLogger=OFF.  Nothing appears to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Eclipse and the messages can be ignored.